# how to get all values from 1st query and only some values from 2nd query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my 1st query gives me [a,b,b,c]

my 2nd query gives me [b,d]

currently im using union all to get all values but that gives me everything from 1st and 2nd query,,

however, what i want is all values from 1st query[a,b,b,c] + some from 2nd query[d] = resultList[a,b,b,c,d]

p/s: i dont want the 'b' from the 2nd query

what method should i use to get resulList??

Comment: Kindly share sample data, query you tried and expected result in formatted text (not images)

Comment: Share what query you have written till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
select * from tableA
union all 
(select * from tableB
where id not in(select*from tableA));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d47c9/1

Answer (score 0):

you can use this structure.

```
select * from TableA
union all 
(select * from TableB
except 
select * from TableA)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8809a/1/0)